# "Bayesian decisioning device"

Tags: probability, bayesian

I've been asked to consider a system using Bayes' Theorem. It has a Boolean input vector x and binary output $y$ = {$0$,$1$}. i.e., $x = {x_1, x_2, ..., x_n}$.

[image]

Given equations:

$p(y=1|x) = \frac{1}{1+exp[-v(x)]}$

$v(x)$ = $log\frac{p(x|y=1)}{p(x|y=0)}$ + $log \frac{p(y=1)}{p(y=0)}$

I'm asked to show that the above equations hold... Is the question asking to find the probability the $y = 1$ given any $x_i$ input? If so, I am not certain how the first equation was calculated.

I was thinking along the lines of using something like $P(y|x) = P(y)\frac{P(x|y)}{P(x)}$ to attempt to prove the first equation correct. That said, I am unsure what $-v(x)$ is in the denominator.

I was able to find in my text the first equation as being the logistic function. So if I am to plot this from some arbitrary values, like -5 to 5, the $v(x)$ value determines the steepness of the curve and that it would cross the y axis at 0.5. But *how* does $v(x)$ affect steepness? Would something like Excel be useful in this scenario to get an accurate graph or could I eyeball it?

I consulted a text I found on Google books and was able to understand $v(x)$ a bit more. It is $log\frac{p(y=1|x)}{p(y=0|x)}$. So $v(x)$ is the log posterior ratio which, as defined above, is the log likelihood ratio + the log prior ratio.

Ok, so I believe I now understand what is being asked as well as the equations given. Are my thoughts above a valid approach or do I need to look in a different direction? If a different direction is needed, any guidance into what that may be is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `\mid` produces proper spacing around vertical bars, which `|` doesn't. Also, `\log` and `\exp` produce the respective function names instead of juxtapositions of italicized variables.

Comment: I see! thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're reading more into these equations than there is. This is just a disguised form of

$$
p(y=1\mid x)=\frac{p(y=1\mid x)}{p(y=0\mid x)+p(y=1\mid x)}\;,
$$

which is what you get if you plug the result you already obtained, $v(x)=\log\frac{p(y=1\mid x)}{p(y=0\mid x)}$, into the upper equation and multiply the fraction through by $p(y=1\mid x)$.

Comment: hmm, yes I see this now.. More algebra than anything it seems. So if I am to plot $p(\,y=1\mid x\,)$, I am assuming the bounds are between 0 and 1 with the function crossing the axis at 0.5, like others I've seen. How would I determine the steepness of the function? I guess this  may be best left up to a computer to determine... I'd like to make the range from some negative to positive, like -5 to +5. The sigmoids I have seen in researching the logistics function all start at 0 and go to some arbitrary positive number. Just curious what would happen at < 0    :)

Comment: @samp1920: $x$ is a vector. You seem to be treating it as a scalar. It's also not quite clear to me what you're plotting in terms of what. My sense is that you're still reading too much into this equation.

Comment: well, I was thinking I would plot multiple instances of $p(\,y=1\mid x\,)$ using different v(x), yielding sigmoids with varying steepness. Not sure if that correctly addreses the vector/scalar issue....

Comment: @samp1920: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do. I think you're barking up the wrong tree. Yes, $1/(1+\exp(-t))$ is a sigmoid. It doesn't have varying steepness; that would have to be $1/(1+\exp(-\lambda t))$. There's no steepness parameter here, just the standard sigmoid. Your notion of varying steepness seems to somehow be related to $x$, but this doesn't make sense, since $x$ is a vector. But maybe I'm just not getting what you're after. Please consider the possibility that the person posing this problem confused you by unnecessarily wrapping a simple equation in a sigmoid.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying now. $x$ is just an input size that I assume the output size is dependent upon. However, this brings about some confusion as to what the conditional probabilities mean. Is the binary output of y dependent simply on the size of x?

Comment: @samp1920: I'm not following you. $x$ is not a size. As I've emphasized several times now, it's a vector. A vector is neither a scalar that can be used as the input for a sigmoid, nor is it a size. As regards $y$, the problem makes no statement whatsoever about what $y$ depends on. It could be entirely independent of $x$ or completely determined by $x$ or anything in between. The equations in the problem are completely general and don't rely on such considerations.

Comment: I should have used magnitude instead of size. Sorry for the confusion. I understand now what you mean by y not being defined as dependent on x. I just assumed that. That said, I really now have no idea how I would plot  $p(y = 1 \mid x)$...

Comment: @samp1920: This seems to be a remarkably persistent confusion. There's nothing to plot here. There's no content. $p(y=1\mid x)$ could be anything. It's the probability that $y$ takes the value $1$ given a certain value of the vector $x$. You have no idea what it is. (Unless there's more to the problem than you've posted.) The entire thing is utterly devoid of content. Stop trying to plot it :-)

Comment: Sorry... I was asked to plot $p(y=1 \mid x)$ for $v(x)$ ranging from 0 to 5. Going back a few comments, this is why I asked what would the function look like if negative values were considered, say -5 to 5. Hopefully this plot is not also devoid of content, otherwise I am not sure why my professor has asked for it.

Comment: @samp1920: Ah. I think I see which comment you're referring to. Sorry, I didn't understand it at the time. Sure, you can plot  $p(y=1\mid x)$ over $v(x)$. That will yield a standard sigmoid. I'm not sure it will be very enlightening, but if your prof thinks so, perhaps it is :-)

Comment: lol hopefully :) Going to attempt in Excel.